# table caption stays below for xtableFtable in R

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I'm trying to use `xtableFtable` with `print` to make a LaTeX table with the caption on top.  I've tried several different variations of what the documentation says about how to change the caption placement within the `print` function, but `print` (as well as `print.xtableFtable`) ignores what I enter for this parameter and uses its default value (which is "bottom").

Here's my code:

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, 
              levels = c("4", "6", "8"), 
              labels = c("four", "six", "eight"))

tbl <- ftable(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs, mtcars$am, 
              col.vars = c(2, 3), 
              dnn = c("Cylinders", "V/S", "Transmission"))

xftbl <- xtableFtable(tbl, 
              method = "non.compact",
              label = "my_table",
              caption = "My Table")

print(xftbl, booktabs = TRUE, 
              caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"))
```

I've also tried these two different variations for the caption placement parameter, but got the same result as above:

```
print(xftbl, booktabs = TRUE, caption.placement = "top")
```

and

```
print(xftbl, booktabs = TRUE,  xtable.caption.placement = "top")
```

All the other parameters appear to work properly, including `booktabs`.  What am I doing wrong with the `caption.placement` parameter?